# What are these pins?

Tags: connector, pins

I was looking at this [component,](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/linear-technology-analog-devices/DC2025A-A/4927129) which has strange interface pins.

I have never seen anything like it.  I wonder how am I supposed to connect to them. What connectors can I use and what's special about them? Is it good for RF stuff for example? What are they called? I could research more if I knew what these pins are called.

[image]

Edit: Answered in the comments: They are turret pins where you wrap a wire and solder to.

Comment: You wrap wire round those and solder it in place.

Comment: 50 yr old swaged turrets  (press-fit)

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond. do you know what are these called?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=swaged+turrets&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03jCGp8b_-PPwbh8TvLN9jxCT_pYw:1596132140097&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE_eXJx_XqAhXQhHIEHZcPBKcQ_AUoAXoECDQQAw&biw=1664&bih=812

Comment: Basically, just pins. Turret pins seems to be a recognised term though.

Comment: The key to find any answer is knowing the correct "key words" = swaged turrets

Comment: exactly @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I just didn't know what are they even called. all good not though. "swagged turrets" that you just solder to. thanks guys!

Comment: no problem for us who grew up with them in the 70's, but good question.. SWAGE process https://www.mill-max.com/engineering-notebooks/introduction-to-swage-assembly

Comment: @himura +1 for the edit and question. Use thick, 1/8" G10/FR-4 epoxy circuit boards using heavy 2-oz double-sided copper and install the turrets into plated holes. The heavy copper lets you swage the turrets to allow a tight mechanical connection on the top and bottom pads, soldered to the bottom pads for truly reliable conductivity. Easy component removal, servicing or modification and stuff can be soldered and desoldered from the turrets *indefinitely* without risk of lifting a circuit pad trace, as the turret itself holds the top and bottom pads and inner plated-through core in place.

Comment: @himura It's a part of what a quality board looks like.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, those [swaged turret pins.](https://www.mill-max.com/engineering-notebooks/introduction-to-swage-assembly)

They are used to connect heavy guage wire to PCBs.

The pin itself is "swaged" onto the PCB - it is rather like a rivet.

The swaging provides mechanical strength.  The pin can also be soldered to the PCB to ensure a good electrical connection.

You can solder wires to the pins to connect things to the PCB.  You can also use clip on wires (alligator clips and similar things) to make temporary connections.  Oscilloscope probes will clip onto them as well.

They probably aren't much good for radio frequency stuff.  There's no way you can really make connection with a given impedance with them.